# Hibernate столбцы со значением по умолчанию.

Tags: hibernate

В таблице messages есть столбец time, по умолчанию current_timestamp. Когда я сохраняю сообщение, вылетает исключение

> Не удалось вставить значение NULL в
> столбец "time", таблицы
> "qa.dbo.messages"; в столбце запрещены
> значения NULL.

А я не хочу вставлять туды Null, я хочу, чтобы таблица сама заполнила поле. Что делать?

```
@Column(name = "time")
private Timestamp time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Короче, согласно ответу [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721818/why-hibernate-dynamic-insert-false-by-default), лучше так не делать, и генерировать значения в коде